# What do we need to guarantee the existence of the extension of a bounded linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

The following question was stated as an exercise:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces over a field $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ a bounded linear operator. Suppose that $T$ is bijective and that $X$ is a closed subspace of a Banach space $X_1$.
>
> > **Q:** Is  any further condition needed to guarantee the existence of a bounded linear operator $T_1 \in \mathcal{L}(X_1,Y)$ with $T_1|_X = T$? if so, what?

My first thought was that these are sufficient conditions to do so, but I have been trying to prove it and I get lost in my reasoning before arriving to any conclusions. After some time dealing with this and looking up for similar questions I don't even know how I should begin... I am a newbie on Banach spaces and Functional Analysis. Any hint you could give me to solve this is widely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is complemented in $X_1$ then the projection $\pi_X :X_1\to X$ is continuous and $T_1 : X_1 \to Y$ $T_1 (x) =T(\pi_X (x))$ is an extension of $T.$

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am aware of this result, but what does fail if $X$ is not assumed to be complemented?